# Creating Boxes Using FlexBox

Tags: javascript, css

To put it into context I am trying to make an etch a sketch game where the boxes will change size to always fill the grid container based on user input. Which is why I can not set a standard height or width. I am attempting to create a certain number of boxes based on user input. It is working except that instead of boxes, rectangles are created that take up the entire height and they change width based on the input. I am trying to make boxes that wrap instead instead of one long rectangle that takes up the entire height. I have messed around with flex wrap and can not figure it out.

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="clear">Clear</button>
        <form id="inputForm">
           <input type="number" class="number" min=1 max=64 placeholder="Enter a # 1-64">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gridContainer">
        <div class="grid"></div>
    </div>
```

````
 body {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

#gridContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
}

.grid {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
} ```
````

```
var form = document.getElementById("inputForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var input = form.querySelector("input");
var boxInput = input.value * input.value;
gridContainer = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
console.log(boxInput);

gridContainer.innerHTML = "";

for (var i = 0; i < boxInput; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    console.log(div);
    div.className = "grid";
    gridContainer.appendChild(div);
}
});
```

Comment: Do you want a NxN grid (N is the user input)? And does it have to be flex? CSS grid would make more sense in this case.

Comment: @haolt I do want the NxN grid based on user input. It does not have to be flex, I will start looking into grid, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said flex are not a requirement, here is how to do that with grid:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("inputForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var input = form.querySelector("input");
  var num = input.valueAsNumber;
  var boxInput = num * num;
  gridContainer = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
  gridContainer.style.setProperty('--num', num);
  //console.log(boxInput);

  gridContainer.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < boxInput; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    //console.log(div);
    div.className = "grid";
    gridContainer.appendChild(div);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

#gridContainer {
  --num: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--num), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--num), 1fr);
}

.grid {
  /*For testing, remove this line if you don't need it*/
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clear">Clear</button>
    <form id="inputForm">
      <input type="number" class="number" min=1 max=64 placeholder="Enter a # 1-64">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="gridContainer">
  <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
```